# CURL or WGET Login, redirect and then submit

Tags: linux, curl, wget

First and foremost linux is by far not my thing but I can understand the basics. 
What I am needing to do is to login to a site, it will redirect me to another page at which point I will need to submit that page. The site does use Session Cookies so I will need to track those in order to perform all of the actions I need.

after reviewing some sites this is what I was able to come up with, but it does not appear to be capturing the session cookies if nothing else
the entire point to this is to set up a cron job that will run a report for me on a weekly basis instead of me having to login to the site and manually perform the tasks

```
curl -d "username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&submit=Llocation --dump-header headers_and_cookies http://example.com?event=loginProcess http://example.com/?event=loginProcess http://example.com/?event=thepromiseland
```

this is the wget that I already had which seems to not work.

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data="username=MyUserName&password=MyPassword"  --no-cache --spider "http://example.com/?event=thepromiseland"
```

Comment: besides the missing double-quote after 'Llocation' in the curl command parameters, this is difficult to diagnose without knowing how the target website is working. By any chance is there Javascript that is necessary for any of that site's login and redirect to work?

Comment: use curl's -c option to store cookies, much better than --dump-header for that purpose... and you probably want curl's -L option as well

Comment: Going off of Daniels suggestion I came out with this which seems to have worked. 
curl -d "username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&submit=Llocation -c -L http://example.com?event=loginProcess http://example.com/?event=loginProcess http://example.com/?event=thepromiseland